# Growing Veggies from Seeds

Tags: vegetables, germination, seedlings

I currently have beefsteak tomatoes, zucchini and peppers that I've started from seeds on May 8th in a seed starting tray indoors.

They seem to be growing well under the light system I have setup.

At what point do I thin the plants? I have 2-3 plants per little hexagonal cell.

When do I move them to bigger containers? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually start thinning seedlings of herbs and vegetables, when they get their 'real' leaves. So I mean when they get more leaves after the first two (cotyledon) leaves.

Comment: and when do you move them to a larger container?

Comment: Thinning or repotting can be done at the same time, it depends a bit on the size of your hexagonal cells. You can also check how much roots are in the current soil, if the soil volume is filled and overcrowded with roots, it is time to put them in larger containers.

Answer (score 1):

Mine were in an egg carton tray for a month or so, from end of February til April. I left them on my stove top under the stove light. But I would take them outside for real sunlight and just water them lightly. They were about an inch tall in the egg carton, clearly ready to take off, before I transplanted them in my raised garden bed. The roots were very dynamic and well formed when I scooped them out of the tray with a spoon. I think you need to make sure they are strong enough to survive the transplant. I had planted about 4 seeds per “egg hole” so some of my plants, like my tomatoes, actually grew 4 plants in one. I just left them together and transplanted them like that. And some only grew the one or two seeds. The roots were too formed to separate them. I think it makes a stronger plant though. You have more chances of producing.